# Is one Thread per Client the answer?

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I have been poring over some research for multithreaded programming, such as [this academic webpage](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~franco/OpSys-304-427/lecture-notes/node67.html/), and have noticed that it is quite popular to create one `Thread` for each client that connects to a given server. In fact, I have found some sample client-server program that does just this. (I attempted to adopt the idea, but now, I am in doubt.) According to Java: How to Program, it is recommended that I use the `ExecutorService` to create and manage `Thread`s since the programmer cannot predict when a `Thread` will actually be dispatched by the system, despite the order in which threads are created and started.

---

**What I intend to do**

As mentioned earlier, I am creating a server that creates a `Thread` for each client. The clients are to send data to me, and the `Thread` will fetch the data, store it in a file, and log the data.

---

**My question**

Would using the `ExecutorService` to create `Thread`s (and manage them!) be effectively the same as giving each client a `Thread` , but more manageable? Also, would it eliminate the overhead caused by the famous "one-thread-per-client" idea?

Answer (score 1):

> Would using the ExecutorService to create Threads (and manage them!) be effectively the same as giving each client a Thread , but more manageable?

yes

> Also, would it eliminate the overhead caused by the famous "one-thread-per-client" idea?

no.  The overhead is usually in terms of the number of active threads which is not changed by using a thread pool.

Comment: Can either way automatically terminate Threads (or are we to use the garbage collection to destroy `Thread`s that have already completed their task (via `System.gc()`)?

Comment: You can have the thread pool shutdown any thread idle for a minute.  This is what the cached thread pool does by default. Since it is only really active threads which matter, you are unlikely to notice the difference.